# how can I analyze "満ちたりていたりした" to make sense?

Tags: meaning

I found the meaning of the phrase in the translated version. But I could not understand the structure of the sentence. 
If you have some idea, please toss me some hints.

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may make more sense if it was written like this instead.

> 満ち足りていたりした

It's just the verb 満ち足りる in て form + いる in たり form + する in past tense.

Comment: That's more than perfect. I appreciate your complete and kind answer~~!!